# Python list of lists depending on length

Tags: python, list

I have the lists below and I need to assign the strings from fruit list into stall list depending on their length.

```
fruit = ['an', 'king', 'be', 'brave']
stall = [[],[],[],[]]
```

So the result should be like this

```
stall = [[ ],['an', 'be'],[ ],['king', 'brave']]
```

I’ve tried so many ways and even attempted to create a new list to see where I am going wrong but not even this is populating anything. Can someone please point me where I am going wrong? I've never had to append to list of lists before.

```
i = 0
s = stall[i]
for j in fruit:
    if(len(j)) == i+1:
        s.append(j)
        i += 1
print(stall)
```

Comment: Why are `king` and `brave` in the same list in your expected output? `brave` has 5 characters.

Comment: I just guess something like `itertools.groupby(iterable, key=len)` will be solution but it will return dict instead of list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want as many inner lists as you need to put in all words correctly:

```
fruit = ['an', 'king', 'be', 'brave']

stall = [
    [element for element in fruit if len(element) == i+1]
    for i in range(len(fruit) + 1)
]
```

`stall` will now be `[[], ['an', 'be'], [], ['king'], ['brave']]`.

Comment: This is very slow for long lists

Comment: @DanielMesejo It's easy optimize such constructs: `itertools` and friends

Comment: @Ingaz No, this approach is quadratic.

Comment: I wrote it like: `[[el for el in fruit if len(el)==cur_len] for cur_len in range(max(map(len, fruit)))]`. Optimization is not a concern in OP question. BUT: if needed one just substitute list of lists into generator of generators. A little more complicated but .. just a little

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if classifying *king* and *brave* together, as your question does, was deliberate or not. I'm assuming deliberate.

```
fruit = ['an', 'king', 'be', 'brave']
stall = [[],[],[],[]]
for f in fruit:
        stall[min(len(f),4)-1].append(f)
```

This will give you

```
>>> stall
[[], ['an', 'be'], [], ['king', 'brave']]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple *O(n)* approach:

```
fruit = ['an', 'king', 'be', 'brave']

lookup = {}
for word in fruit:
    lookup.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word)

stall = [lookup.get(i, []) for i in range(1, max(lookup) + 1)]

print(stall)
```

An alternative using using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

fruit = ['an', 'king', 'be', 'brave']

lookup = defaultdict(list)
for word in fruit:
    lookup[len(word)].append(word)

stall = [lookup.get(i, []) for i in range(1, max(lookup) + 1)]

print(stall)
```

**Output**

```
[[], ['an', 'be'], [], ['king'], ['brave']]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be following. First you get the size of the empty list `stall` from the dimensions of the largest string in your `fruit`. Then you simply append the fruits to the corresponding position in your nested lists.

The `len(f)-1` is used because the indexing in python starts from 0.

```
fruit = ['an', 'king', 'be', 'brave']
stall = [[] for _ in range(len(max(fruit, key=len)))]

for f in fruit:
    stall[len(f)-1].append(f)

print (stall)
# [[], ['an', 'be'], [], ['king'], ['brave']]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
v_test_list = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1]]

maxLen = max(map(len, v_test_list ))
for row in v_test_list :
while len(row) < maxLen:
     row.append('-')
 print(v_test_list)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, '-'], [1, '-', '-']]
```